# Use list comprehension without iteration variable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I wonder if there is a way to use e.g. a list comprehension without an iteration variable if I do not need it? For example, in this sample of code:

```
a = [random.randrange(-10, 11) / 10 for i in range(100)]
```

I get a warning *"Local variable 'i' value is not used"*. Is there any variant of the list comprehension construct without iteration variable?

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using? You might be able to change `i` to `_` which is the common notation for "I deliberately mean to not be using this" and your IDE might ignore it, but otherwise - it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just discard the value of `i`:

```
a = [random.randrange(-10, 11) / 10 for _ in range(100)]
```

> `_` is considered the "last value" in Python and by convention is
>   used as a "throw away" value.

Comment: warning disappeared, but does that mean we are now using unnecessary variable _ instead of i?

Comment: ``_`` is considered the "last value" in Python and by convention is used as a "throw away" value.

Comment: @zegoline Just need to be careful if you're using Python 2.x and have `ugettext` or which is commonly aliased as `_` (another convention) as a list-comp in Py 2.x will leak `_` to the outer scope.

Comment: `_` is only the last value in the interactive interpreter. In a script it has no special meaning.

Comment: If you read what I said *carefully* that's precisely what I mean :)